# Como mostrar imagem da storage do Laravel com Ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho um projeto que analisa imagens e retorna um frame e algumas variáveis, dentro da `/storage/imagens/` onde salvo a imagem analisada mas não sei fazer com que isso seja puxado pelo ajax e colocado dentro da `src` de uma `div` ou `img`. Estava criando uma Controller que buscava o arquivo dentro da imagens e então tratava, colocava em um Json e assim o ajax consumia e inseria no src. Alguém pode me dar um método mas fácil de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu *controller* serve diretamente um arquivo de imagem, você pode criar um `Blob`, usando o `fetch`, para em seguida gerar uma URL.

No exemplo abaixo, a URL que estamos requisitando é um arquivo de imagem qualquer. Mas no seu caso, basta trocar pela URL da sua aplicação que serve o arquivo da imagem.

Enfim, você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
// Coloque a URL que retorna a imagem do controller:
const endpoint = 'https://lffg-archive.github.io/sopt/img.png?img=png';

const placeholder = document.querySelector('#img-placeholder');

async function loadImage(uri, el) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(uri);

    if (response.status >= 400) {
      console.error('Houve algum erro ao carregar.');
      return false;
    }

    const blob = await response.blob();

    // Criamos uma URL a partir do blob:
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Adicionamos a URL gerada na imagem:
    el.src = url;
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Houve algum erro:', error.message);
    return false;
  }
}

loadImage(endpoint, placeholder)
  .then(() => console.log('Done.'));
```

```html
<img id="img-placeholder" width="200" height="200" />
```

A título de curiosidade: é assim que muitos vídeos na internet são carregados, apesar de que na maioria das vezes vários processos são adicionados para evitar o *download* desses arquivos.

---

Ou você pode simplesmente adicionar o `src` na imagem diretamente, sem precisar de complicar! :)

```
<img src="{{ $image_url }}" />
```